# How can I improve this function so that it overwrites the Excel cell?

Tags: javascript, excel, exceljs

I'm using this code to try and overwrite a cell in Excel:

```
function readExcelFile(workbook, row, cell, newData) {
    workbook.xlsx.readFile('H://filename.xlsm')
        .then(function () {
            cell.value = newData;
            row.commit();
            return workbook.xlsx.writeFile('H://newFile.xlsx');
        });
}
```

I can get the data logged to the console, but the Excel file stays the same.

Any help would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably, the function parameters `row` and `cell` are objects related to `workbook`? However, they'll lose this connection within the scope of the anonymous function where you're writing the file. (Technically speaking, JavaScript passes variables to functions by value and not by reference.)

Instead pass the info needed to find the cell, and get it locally within the function:

```
function readExcelFile(workbook, worksheetName, rowIndex, columnIndex, newData) {
    workbook.xlsx.readFile('H://filename.xlsm')
        .then(function () {
            worksheet = workbook.getWorksheet(worksheetName);
            row = worksheet.getRow(rowIndex);
            cell = row.getCell(columnIndex);
            cell.value = newData;
            row.commit();
            return workbook.xlsx.writeFile('H://newFile.xlsx');
        });
}

readExcelFile(my_workbook, "My Worksheet", 3, 3, 34232);
```

Comment: Hi @miken32, thanks for your answer, it looks like even in the same scope, the only cells that change are ones that were already empty. I need to change the value of non-empty cells as well.

I also realise that I didn't tell you I am using the exceljs npm package

Comment: You tagged it exceljs which is fine. You didn’t mention that you were able to write to empty cells though. Maybe see if the edits I made work any better.   Making up a [mcve] is always a good exercise. It makes it easier to answer a question and a lot of the time it helps you figure out the problem without having to post a question at all!